# ransack: how to get no results by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, rubygems

when I use ransack to search in my rails 3.2 app, I get a list of all items when I submit the search form with all fields blank.

How can get no items when doing a blank search?

Comment: why you try with validation "can't be blank?"

Comment: I got multiple search fields and so I think it would be more complex than just set a default value for the search result